# Django: using ._get_deleted_forms and custom formset saving

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm attempting to provide some custom formset handling. The user has the option of deleting a form and adding a form. Within the same function I'm trying to remove the associated object and add new objects. This is an example of the code I'm working on:

```
def addCategories(movie, category_formset):
    if category_formset.deleted_forms:
        for form in category_formset._get_deleted_forms:
            obj_to_remove = form.save(commit=False)
            movie.categories.remove(obj_to_remove)
    for form in category_formset:
        if form.cleaned_data.get('name') is not None:
            obj = Category.objects.get_or_create_category(form.cleaned_data.get('name'))
            movie.categories.add(obj)
    movie.save()
```

The problem is that I don't think I'm using ._get_deleted_forms correctly. It claims that category_formset._get_deleted_forms is not iterable. And I'm not sure if this would work anyway -- since it might just add the deleted object right back to the model in the second for loop. Any ideas?

A workaround that doesn't seem very efficient:

```
def addCategories(recipe, category_formset):

    if category_formset.deleted_forms:
        for form in category_formset:
            if form in category_formset.deleted_forms:
                obj_to_remove = form.save(commit=False)
                recipe.categories.remove(obj_to_remove)
            else:
                if form.cleaned_data.get('name') is not None:
                    obj = Category.objects.get_or_create_category(form.cleaned_data.get('name'))
                    recipe.categories.add(obj)
    else:
        for form in category_formset:
            if form.cleaned_data.get('name') is not None:
                obj = Category.objects.get_or_create_category(form.cleaned_data.get('name'))
                recipe.categories.add(obj) 
    recipe.save()
```